# Is there a way to reference the index of the button above of a clicked button? In Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to move an object to the button above the one I'm clicking, like this `board[i-1][j].setText("X")` Since I'm doing this in a for loop I don't need to find the specific index, I just want to reference it.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (((JButton)e.getSource()).getText().equals("\u2193") && hasWinner == false &&) {
        button.setText(currentPlayer);
        if(i<=1){
           board[i-1][j].setText("X");
        }
```

Comment: Use two for loops, nested to loop through your 2D array of button to see which button matches the source button, and then get the indices of the match from the for loop indices (as per the duplicate)

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: no. They can use my suggestion above, or they can put the value of the row and column into the JButton on creation using the [putClientProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#putClientProperty(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)) and related `getClientProperty` methods.